# Как сделать проверку, является ли символ строки цифрой?

Tags: c#

Как в условии if-а сделать проверку - является ли символ строки цифрой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7f0ddtxh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)